# Наследование jpa

Tags: java, jpa

Есть 2 таблицы(table0 и table1), у них одинаковый id. Table1 берет id у table0. В перспективе планируется добавление еще таблиц подобных table1. Для различения дочерних таблиц на table0 есть поле table_type_name.

```
@Entity
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.JOINED)
@DiscriminatorColumn(name = "table_type_name", discriminatorType = DiscriminatorType.STRING)
@Table(name = "table0", schema = "my_schema")
public abstract class Table0 {
        @Id
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "TableSeq")
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "TableSeq", schema = "ap", sequenceName = "AP_TABLE_ID_SEQ", allocationSize = 1)
    @Column(name = "table_id")
    private Long tableId;

    @Column(name = "table_type_name")
    private String type;
}
```

```
@Entity
@DiscriminatorValue(TABLE1_TYPE)
@Table(name = "table1", schema = "my_schema")
public class Table1 extends Table0{//some code}
```

В общем я пытаюсь связать table0 и table1 по типу TABLE1_TYPE, и сохранить в бд через table1 данные этих 2х таблиц.

При сохранении в логах такая ошибка:

```
org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: The column index is out of range: 8, number of columns: 7.
```

Попробовал создать отдельную сущность на table0 - все сохранилось успешно, подозреваю на @Inheritance/@DiscriminatorColumn